# Project / code release strategy

Tags: language-agnostic, versioning, release, policy

Context: I work at a small software company that has traditionally done research-type work, and does not have much experience in the commercial space. We are now trying to push into the commercial world. Due to our origins in research we are used to a very rapid development cycle and very little structure in terms of maintaining proper versions of projects.

Problem: The lack of structure is now proving to be somewhat of a hindrance, as every developer has a slightly different view of the code base. A problem one developer discovers is not reproducible by another developer, and problems found in one build may disappear in the next (or worse, new problems may appear). This makes for a very frustrating experience for someone who is responsible for integrating all the projects and ensuring quality and performance standards are met - i.e. myself.

Potential solution: Personally I am convinced we need to enforce better structure via fixed version numbers and regular releases. It should be self-evident how proper versioning would help with many of our problems, but of course it is not without problems - developers need to do extra work to perform and test releases, and will no longer be able to use the latest versions of everything.

Question: To come to a point - what sorts of strategies do you recommend for ensuring the process and effort required for releases occurs as smoothly as possible? We are using git for version control, maven for our build system, and we have bug tracking and continuous integration systems running, so I believe the tools are there. I am simply unsure about what a proper release process should look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the big three in place: version control, one-click build via Maven and your continuous build server, and bug tracking.  It sounds like you guys are gravitating towards Agile methodologies, and so you ought to be trying to keep the trunk version of your product in a near deliverable state at all times.

When you decide to make your first release, create a branch off of your trunk version for that release.  Decide on a labelling scheme and be sure to label the branch version.  For example, your first release could be 1.0.4530, where the 1 means first version, the 0 means it's the first release candidate, and the 4530 is the version control change number.  You test this release branch and fix important bugs on it.  After a while you issue another release candidate, say 1.1.4807.  This process iterates a couple more times (say), your release becomes good enough, and you ship version 1.3.5167.

Meanwhile, your new development occurs only in the trunk version, and from time to time you'll need to merge bug fixes from the 1.x release branch back to the trunk.  Later, you'll split off a 2.x branch from the trunk to repeat the process for your second release.  You'll generally have several active branches (plus the trunk), with development limited to the trunk and each branch kept pristine and independent from development.

You guys will get the hang of things and your developer coordination problems will become less frequent.  But these problems are nearly all going to be limited to the trunk, not the release branches.

Answer (score 2):

> A problem one developer discovers is
>   not reproducible by another developer,
>   and problems found in one build may
>   disappear in the next (or worse, new
>   problems may appear). This makes for a
>   very frustrating experience for
>   someone who is responsible for
>   integrating all the projects and
>   ensuring quality and performance
>   standards are met - i.e. myself.
>
> Potential solution: Personally I am
>   convinced we need to enforce better
>   structure via fixed version numbers
>   and regular releases.

I don't think you need to have very frequent releases just to coordinate internally.  You can do that through version control.  Just have people talk about specific git revisions when reporting issues.  Also note that you will have to coordinate any external dependencies/libraries too.  Some kind of [vendor branches](http://happygiraffe.net/blog/2008/02/07/vendor-branches-in-git/) could help with this.

Comment: Vendor branches look interesting. Talking about specific revisions isn't really an option because we have 50+ commits a day over dozens of projects, so asking our developers to continually enumerate and sync up on versions would take an excessive amount of times. Version numbers denoted via tags / branches would make this synch process much easier.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like the developers need to use "test branches" and respect the "stable/production branch" a little bit more.

Sell in the concept of "do your wild west stuff in this branch", and when you are happy with the results then you merge it into this "boring stable production branch"....
(or something like that)

Answer (score 0):

There are books written about the general topic; Amazon search even returns three titles for specialized "version control with git."

I think you will benefit from defining a canonical view of the code base.  Call it Test.  A problem is a problem if it appears in Test.  If a problem does not appear in some developer's view, it is up to that developer to figure out what is the important difference; and likewise for a problem that appears in a developer's view, but not in Test.

One convention is for Test to be re-built from sources on a nightly basis.  A more strenuous convention is for Test to be re-built upon every update.  If your team is small (five or fewer) and not dispersed over great distances or multiple timezones, a reasonable first approximation is to make Test a git workspace on a server upon which your toolchain has been installed along with some cron jobs so that this workspace is updated and rebuilt every night (usually).